# Unique alphanumeric key generation in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, key

I have table with char(4) field which is used as key. Value for that is generated (max + 1). But not it has reached to it's max(9999). Cannot change the data type of the column since that is used it so many places.

I came up with a solution like below...

9999 -> A000...A999->B000...B999->Z999 -> ZA00->ZZZZ (zzzz will be OK for another 10 years)

Please tell me is there an easy way to generate this other than doing substring() and string manipulation ?

Current Code :

```
DECLARE @cle smallint
SELECT @cle = isnull(MAX(CONVERT(smallint,RTRIM(cle))),0) from smnf
INSERT INTO smnf (sup, cle, dsc, exc, dirty) VALUES (@sup, CONVERT(char(4), @cle+1), @dsc, 0, 'A')
```

Comment: Can you show what your code is?  It's hard to tell if something else is easier.  Also, wy not just use an integer identity column.

Comment: DECLARE @ cle smallint
SELECT @ cle = isnull(MAX(CONVERT(smallint,RTRIM(cle))),0) from smnf
INSERT INTO smnf (sup, cle, dsc, exc, dirty) VALUES (@sup, CONVERT(char(4), @ cle+1), @ dsc, 0, 'A')

Using integer is not possible now since this is field uses by 100+ applications

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i INTO #t FROM (SELECT '0' i UNION ALL SELECT '1' UNION ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL SELECT '3' UNION ALL SELECT '4' UNION ALL SELECT '5' UNION ALL SELECT '6' UNION ALL SELECT '7' UNION ALL SELECT '8' UNION ALL SELECT '9' UNION ALL SELECT 'A' UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'C' UNION ALL SELECT 'D' UNION ALL SELECT 'E' UNION ALL SELECT 'F' UNION ALL SELECT 'G' UNION ALL SELECT 'H' UNION ALL SELECT 'I' UNION ALL SELECT 'J' UNION ALL SELECT 'K' UNION ALL SELECT 'L' UNION ALL SELECT 'M' UNION ALL SELECT 'N' UNION ALL SELECT 'O' UNION ALL SELECT 'P' UNION ALL SELECT 'Q' UNION ALL SELECT 'R' UNION ALL SELECT 'S' UNION ALL SELECT 'T' UNION ALL SELECT 'U' UNION ALL SELECT 'V' UNION ALL SELECT 'W' UNION ALL SELECT 'X' UNION ALL SELECT 'Y' UNION ALL SELECT 'Z') t

CREATE TABLE id_list (id char(4) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT id_list
SELECT c1.i+c2.i+c3.i+c4.i
FROM #t c1, #t c2, #t c3, #t c4
WHERE c1.i+c2.i+c3.i+c4.i NOT LIKE '[0-9]%[A-Z]%'  --Eliminate alphas in the first 10000 to preserve existing ids.
```

When you need the next id:

```
DECLARE @curr_id char(4) = '9ZZZ'
DECLARE @next_id char(4)

SELECT TOP 1 @next_id = [id] FROM id_list WHERE [id] > @curr_id

PRINT @next_id
```

A000

Comment: Tried, it works for SQL2K. But new id is not the one expected. As I said on the question I need A000 after 9999. But in here it returns 999A after 9999

Comment: Just looked at the table(id_list). In my case numeric should run up to 9999 (it is already filled up, I cannot change already created ids)

Comment: According to your plan, what would come after '9A99'?

Comment: there cannot be a situation '9A99' since it has to come max ('Z') before moving to next. ex. 'ZA99'

Comment: That's a horrible plan. You want your keys in a sortable order.